# OpenCV contour minimum dimension location in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am using background subtraction to analyse moving objects of an outdoor scene.  When the sun comes out I have a problem with shadows. I am using contours to isolate the objects. At the moment I simply analyse the top half of the contour as the shadow is normally in the bottom half.

Imagine a contour of a rubber duck, what I would like to do is to find the y position of the neck of the duck, that is where the contour is at its minimum horizontal dimension.
Could someone please point me in the right direction of how to find the "neck of the duck"?

[image]

In the code, `binary` is a threshold image of the moving objects, `HIGHT` and `WIDTH` are the height and width of the image, `lab` is the same image in the LAB color space.

I would like to replace the `half = int(h/2)` line with a function to find the y position of a horizontal line to cut the "ducks neck" off.

```
_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(binary.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# loop over the contours
for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):

   # compute the bounding box for the contour
   (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

   # reject contours outside size range
   if w > 250 or w < 30 or h > 250 or h < 30 :
          continue

   # make sure the box is inside the frame
   if x <= 0 or y <= 0 or x+w >= (WIDTH -1) or y+h >= (HIGHT -1):
          continue

   # isolate feature
   half = int(h/2)
   roi = lab[y:y+half, x:x+w]
   mask = binary[y:y+half, x:x+w]

   # calculate the mean of the colour
   mean = cv2.mean(roi, mask = mask)
   # note: mean is L a b
   L = int(mean[0])
   a = int(mean[1])
   b = int(mean[2])
   print L,a,b
```

I am using opencv 3 and python 2.7

P.S. I have tried the background subtractor MOG2 which is said to identify shadows but it is way to noisy for my use and not viable.

Comment: Add to your question a few images with actual and expected results. Click on the edit link under the tags. You don't have enough reputation to add image, but you can post a public link from imgur or similar

Comment: Hi Miki, I have added a sketch which should help clarify, please feel free to ask anything else.  I have thought of 3 possible solutions, 1) Somehow use moments, 2) Iterate through the contour list to find turning points, 3) Sum rows horizontally to get a profile and then find turning points of the profile.  The first two I have no idea about so some help on how to use moments or how to access and interpret the contour list would be of great help.  Or any other suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain when you're trying to do as asked but please avoid Dropbox/other transient links if at all possible - we want these questions to help people for years and if you delete your dropbox file in future, it would make this question less valuable. SO Have an arrangement with imgur to make sure all images will be around for the duration. I've done it for you in this instance. Hope you find your answer!

Comment: i'm not an OpenCV expert but I don't believe this approach will ever be entirely accurate as I can't see a way to differentiate between a ball in sunshine and a "real" rubber duck with no shadow. Even more complex would be a real duck with shadow = three pinch points. Do you have any other input to indicate that shadows should be expected/not?

Comment: Hi Basic, you are right but it does not have to be 100% as I build a feature vector later in the code and use a clustering method to identify the type of object.  My question is limited to just this step in my code so that I can use more of the actual object to calculate my feature vectors rather than loose half of the object when there is no sun.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a mask to erode the image, so that you can break the top and bottom blobs from the valley. You can apply that to your code like the following:

```
# loop over the contours
for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):

   # compute the bounding box for the contour
   (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

   # reject contours outside size range
   if w > 250 or w < 30 or h > 250 or h < 30 :
          continue

   # make sure the box is inside the frame
   if x <= 0 or y <= 0 or x+w >= (WIDTH -1) or y+h >= (HIGHT -1):
          continue

   # ---------------
   # create a mask for erosion, you can play with the mask size/shape
   mask = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5))
   # erode the original image
   eroded_img = cv2.erode(binary,mask,iterations = 1)
   cv2.imshow("Eroded image",eroded_img)
   # find the middle of the two new contours
   _,new_contours,_ = cv2.findContours(eroded_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                      cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
   (_, y_t, _, h_t) = cv2.boundingRect(new_contours[0])
   (_, y_b, _, h_b) = cv2.boundingRect(new_contours[1])
   bottom_top_y = max(y_t, y_b) # highest y of bottom part
   top_bottom_y = min(y_t+h_t, y_b+h_b) # lowest y of top part
   half = top_bottom_y + (bottom_top_y - top_bottom_y)/2
   # ------------

   # isolate feature
   roi = lab[y:y+half, x:x+w]
   mask = binary[y:y+half, x:x+w]

   # calculate the mean of the colour
   mean = cv2.mean(roi, mask = mask)
   # note: mean is L a b
   L = int(mean[0])
   a = int(mean[1])
   b = int(mean[2])
   print L,a,b
```

Hope it helps! For more examples on morphological operations on binary images, you can check [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html?highlight=morphological).

Comment: Ike, thanks very much for your input.  This is definitely one way to do it.  I already use erode to reduce the mask size so that the very edges of the object are not included in my recognition calculations.  Maybe I will erode in a loop until there are 2 contours and then grow the top contour back to near original size.  Cheers :-)